# Truffle fails to migrate an Oraclize contract into Ganache

Tags: oracles, truffle-migration, ganache

I have a contract that is using Oraclize.

When deploying the contract from the Remix IDE into Ganache/Ethereum-bridge via MetaMask, the contract is fully functional. However, when trying to migrate the contract from Truffle into Ganache/Ethereum-bridge, I am getting the following error:

```
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Deploying ContractOne...
  ... (TX_ADDRESS)
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.
```

*Note, `TX_ADDRESS` is the transaction address I masked here.*

My `2_deploy_contracts.js` file:

```
var ContractOne = artifacts.require("./ContractOne.sol");
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(ContractOne, "FROM ADDRESS");
};
```

`truffle.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id,
      gas: 4700000,
      gasPrice: 40
    }
  }
};
```

Tried changing the gas amount, adding the gas amount into the deployer - nothing works. At this moment, I suspect the issue is in Oraclize contract using abstract functions, though I'm not sure. What could be the source of this error?

**UPD:** It seems that the issue is in `__callback()` function of Oraclize, though I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The situation is possible, because Remix compiles solidity with optimization by default, Truffle compiles without optimization, that is why gas usage can be different.

I would suggest to remove

```
gas: 4700000,
gasPrice: 40
```

from truffle config and run truffle with optimizer.

Hope it will help

Comment: Didn't help, unfortunately. Still getting the same error.

Comment: @Ruham you can try to increase `gas` twice to clarify the issue. if transaction pass, most probably issue with compiler settings (version), if doesn't, problem in code.